# How can i Trigger api from ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I have given my MY API handler below. i don't know how can trigger the get api from view controller

```swift
class GetPromotionApiHandler {
    static let sharedInstance = GetPromotionApiHandler()
   
    func callingPromoAPI(completionHandler: @escaping Handler) {
        
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                    "correlationId": "myYt005",
                    "operation": "promotions",
                    "destination": "CRM",
                    "source": "WEB",
                    "srDate": "16-05-2022",
                    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ0ZW5hbnRUeXBlIjoiY2xpZW50IiwidGVuYW5jeUlkIjoiTVZOT19XRUJfUFRDIiwibG9naW5Vc2VybmFtZSI6Ijk2NzEwMTkwNTU0MSIsImxvZ2luVHlwZSI6ImRldmljZUlkIiwiYXBwSWQiOiIyYWYyMzI3Mi1hZTNjLTM3ODItYWIwYS0xOTdlMzcyZWQ4NzkiLCJhY2NvdW50Tm8iOiJTQTEyMjM2NDQiLCJ0b2tlblR5cGUiOiJ1c2VyVG9rZW4iLCJleHAiOjE2ODc4MDMwMTIsImlhdCI6MTY4Nzc1OTgxMiwiZW1haWwiOiJtb2JpbGVhcHAxMjNAeW9wbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.VrgJS12Xnf59MjgjHoxdKPGmsCdxwfOzLZbX4vefdJ2y6mPH3T6BfIZbAq2trWQeB4R92b8s_XAOTkA_6zvRBw"
        ]
        AF.request(promotion_url, method: .get,  headers: headers).response{
                response in
            debugPrint(response)
            switch response.result{
            case .success(let data):
                do{
                    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([Promotions].self, from: data!)
                    if response.response?.statusCode == 200{
                        completionHandler(.success(json))
                    }else{
                        completionHandler(.failure(.custom(message: "Please check your Network Network Connectivity")))
                    }
                }catch{
                    completionHandler(.failure(.custom(message: "Please Try again")))
                }
            case .failure(let err):
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                completionHandler(.failure(.custom(message: "Please Try again")))
            }



        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `GetPromotionApiHandler.sharedInstance.callingPromoAPI{ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

In this case there are 2 solutions. One of which @RickyMo mentioned as a comment to just call it directly through it's singleton instance:
`GetPromotionApiHandler.sharedInstance.callingPromoAPI{ ... }`

The other option that i would strongly recommend is to make a depency injection of the handler with maybe the defaulted value of sharedInstance. Something like this:

```
class ViewController {
    
    private let apiHandler: GetPromotionApiHandler
    
    init(apiHandler: GetPromotionApiHandler = .sharedInstance) {
        self.apiHandler = apiHandler
    }
    
    func doCall() {
        apiHandler.callingPromoAPI { event in
            // Handle event
        }
    }
}
```

In the future you can wrap the call functions in the ApiHandler in a protocol and mock the result from your request function, sending in a fake ApiHandler in the test environment. Very UnitTest friendly